# Pseudo-magnet implementation with chipmunk

Tags: physics, chipmunk

How should I go about implementing "natural" magnet on a certain body in chipmunk space? Context is of simple bodies lying in the space (think chessboard). When one of the figures is activated as a magnet - others should start moving towards it.

Currently I'm applying force (`cpBodyApplyForce`)to the other figures with vector calculated towards the activated figure. However this doesn't really feel "natural". Are there any known algorithms for imitating magnets?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's been a while since I did magnets, but I believe that [the equation you want is the naive model of the force between two poles](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Force_between_magnets#Force_between_two_magnetic_poles).

```
def force(a, b):
    magnitude = a.magnitude * b.magnitude
    separation_sq = distance_squared(a.position, b.position)
    return (permeability * magnitude) / (4 * pi * separation_sq)
```

For your purposes, you can probably fix `permeability` at 4 * pi and tweak only the per-object magnitudes to get the feel you want, simplifying the equation:

```
def force(a, b):
    magnitude = a.magnitude * b.magnitude
    separation_sq = distance_squared(a.position, b.position)
    return magnitude / separation_sq
```

The important part is that the force varies inversely with the square of the distance between the objects.